# Trouble aligning inputs in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code and I'm trying to get both of these inputs aligned centered. Where is the problem in the code?

```
<div class='form'>
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
  <div class="text-center input-group input-group-lg">
    <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
    <input class="text-center form-control" align="middle" placeholder="username"         name="username" type="text">
  </div>

  <div class="text-center input-group input-group-lg">
    <span class="input-group-addon">P</span>
    <input class="text-center form-control" align="middle" placeholder="password" name="password" type="password">
  </div>

</form>
</div>

<style>
.text-center {
width: 50%;
}

div {
text-align:center;

}

</style>
```

Both inputs are still aligned to the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inputs are not text, and cannot be centered using text-align. Target the element directly in your css, like so:

```
input {
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This will center the inputs within the parent element.